# Detect if Cam is front or back

Tags: android, camera

I take a picture with android :

```
bComenzarVisita.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            imageFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_PIC_INI_REQUEST);

        }
    });
```

The thing is when the user use front cam, the pic get flipped, and I want to rotate it in this case. Rotating and flipping is no problem.

How can I know in the method : onActivityResult which camera the user has used ( front or back)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case CAMERA_PIC_INI_REQUEST:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // If front camera used, flip pic
        }
        break;
...
           }
 }
```

Comment: the CameraInfo object holds information about front or rear camera. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html)

Comment: I understand if I need to use it, I will need to implement my own SurfaceView ( API > 9) : http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-detect-if-image-has-86481.S.202897520. Is there another way to use built in camera?